# I am unable to dynamically populate a product into product page in MERN STACK?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

This is Product route to get one product on basis of ID

If any body want to help me i can share the source code with him /her as well

```
router.get("/oneproduct/:id", getOneProduct)
```

This is Controller of this route

```
  const getOneProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      let oneProduct = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
      res.status(200).send({ status: "All products are here", oneProduct });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
```

This is product page route in React js front-end

```
 const location = useLocation()
  const id = location.pathname.split('/')[2]
  // console.log(id)
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({})
  console.log(product)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  // console.log(product)
  const handleAdd = () => {


  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getproduct = async () => {
        try {
        let res=await publicRequest.get(`products/oneproduct/`+id)
        setProduct(res.data) 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }  
      getproduct()
  }, [id])
```

Comment: What is `publicRequest`?

Comment: Bro i can share the source code can you help me

Comment: import axios from "axios"

const BASE_URL="http://localhost:80/api/"
const Token=""
export const publicRequest=axios.create({

    baseURL:BASE_URL,
    })

export const userRequest=axios.create({
    
    baseURL:BASE_URL,
    headers:{token:`Bearer ${Token}`}
})